# Double sort in Excel or SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have a weird table-sorting issue that I cannot figure out in Excel or SQL.

Here's a table sorted by column 2, "Letter".

| Name | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| Dan | A |
| Moe | A |
| Ted | B |
| Dan | C |
| Joe | F |
| Noe | F |

What I need is the table sorted by Letter BUT... if there are any duplicates in the "Name" column, I need those grouped--which would break the sorting in column 2. So below, even though the table is sorted by Letter, I want the two Dans together:

| Name | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| Dan | A |
| Dan | C |
| Moe | A |
| Ted | B |
| Joe | F |
| Noe | F |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What kind of database are you querying?  There are probably different SQL solutions for this depending on the vendor.

Comment: T-SQL, sorry I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this.

```
SELECT t.name, t.letter
  FROM table t
  JOIN (SELECT table.name, MIN(table.letter) AS min_letter_by_name
          FROM table GROUP BY table.name)
    ON t.name = table.name
  ORDER BY min_letter_by_name, name, letter
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an odd ordering with that one, but perhaps that's because I'm in TSQL

Comment: @SashaSQL I think I made a mistake in the ORDER BY sequence.  I've modified it, see if that gives what you want.

Comment: Mother of god I think that might be it, Dave. Have to test on my large sample

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really say where in the results you wanted the Dans but let's use a window function to count the number of same names and sort by that initially (descending, meaning the dans will sort nearer the top)

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name) DESC, letter
```

If you have eg two Fred and you want them to sort together and not mix up with the dans, consider

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE name END DESC, letter
```

This effectively puts unique names "in one basket" that is then sorted by letter and for "non unique names" they clump together by the name and then sort by the letter

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! I get an odd ordering with that one. What I need is the table ordered by Letter, THEN for any duplicates ('Dans') I need them next to each other--without altering the overall order of the Letter column.

Comment: Seems to deliver the requested result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=031fcbfebe90e378d4468edf5156d554 - please refine your specification. If the complaint is that noe/joe are in the wrong order, add `name` at the end of the order spec. You should perhaps consider that your ordering specification is incomplete. We have no idea what to do if there are two freds, nor X people with the same letter

Comment: Hey, yes that's the ordering! The only issue is that the actual table is thousands on rows with thousands of different values etc; I created this small model just to simplify. It's a table of phone numbers ("Letters" here) and I need the phone numbers ordered, but if there are any duplicates in the Names column, they have to be grouped together, while keeping the Phone ordering otherwise intact

Answer (score 1):

This Power Query solution (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365) seems to do what you want on your database.

Please read the comments.

I group by Name and then sort by letter (as well as sort each subGroup by letter).

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Letter", type text}}),

//Group by name
//Sort each subgroup and extract the initial letter
//Generate a Table with each subtable properly sorted
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [Name=nullable text, Letter=nullable text]},
        {"SortSubGroup", each Table.Sort(_,"Letter")},
        {"letter1", each List.Sort([Letter]){0}, type text}
        }),

//Sort by initial letter and then by Name
//Remove the unneeded columns and expand the subTables
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"letter1", Order.Ascending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Name", "All", "letter1"}),
    #"Expanded SortSubGroup" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "SortSubGroup", {"Name", "Letter"}, {"Name", "Letter"})
in
    #"Expanded SortSubGroup"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two keys in your `order by` clause:

```
order by name, letter
```

EDIT:

If you want to sort by `name` based on the *lowest* letter, then you would use window functions:

```
order by min(letter) over (partition by name),
         name, letter
```

Comment: That would not yield the requested results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Adding Letter to the second position in the ORDER BY just sorts the names _within_ the duplicates in the Letter column sort, if that makes sense; so you get Dan who's letter A followed by Moe who's the other A.

Comment: @SashaSQL . . . Did you run this?  It puts all the Dan's together.  It does not interleave them.

Comment: I haven’t yet but I will tomorrow. Thank you.